# Modification of xml schema to add Root element and no namespaces

Tags: xml, xsd, schema

Could anyone help me in modifying the xsd so that a Root element is added at the top of the xml with two attributes, also the namespace is not needed in the xml and therefore not needed in schema

Current schema

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsdLocal="http://abcorp/json/org" targetNamespace="http://abcorp/json/org" attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified">
   <xsd:annotation>
      <xsd:documentation>Sampleschema</xsd:documentation>
   </xsd:annotation>
   <xsd:element name="a" type="xsdLocal:a" />
   <xsd:complexType name="aTopElmt">
      <xsd:sequence>
         <xsd:element name="a" type="xsdLocal:a" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" />
      </xsd:sequence>
   </xsd:complexType>
   <xsd:complexType name="a">
      <xsd:sequence>
         <xsd:element name="b" type="xsdLocal:b" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" />
      </xsd:sequence>
   </xsd:complexType>
   <xsd:complexType name="b">
      <xsd:sequence>
         <xsd:element name="c" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" />
         <xsd:element name="d" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" />
         <xsd:element name="e" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" />
         <xsd:element name="f" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" />
         <xsd:element name="g" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" />
         <xsd:element name="h" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" />
         <xsd:element name="i" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" />
         <xsd:element name="j" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" />
         <xsd:element name="k" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" />
         <xsd:element name="l" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" />
      </xsd:sequence>
   </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:schema>
```

xml current

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsdLocal:a xmlns:xsdLocal="http://abcorp/json/org" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://abcorp/json/org target.xsd ">
  <xsdLocal:b>
    <xsdLocal:c>xsdLocal:c</xsdLocal:c>
    <xsdLocal:d>xsdLocal:d</xsdLocal:d>
    <xsdLocal:e>xsdLocal:e</xsdLocal:e>
    <xsdLocal:f>xsdLocal:f</xsdLocal:f>
    <xsdLocal:g>xsdLocal:g</xsdLocal:g>
    <xsdLocal:h>xsdLocal:h</xsdLocal:h>
    <xsdLocal:i>xsdLocal:i</xsdLocal:i>
    <xsdLocal:j>xsdLocal:j</xsdLocal:j>
    <xsdLocal:k>xsdLocal:k</xsdLocal:k>
    <xsdLocal:l>xsdLocal:l</xsdLocal:l>
  </xsdLocal:b>
</xsdLocal:a>
```

Now the schema has to be modified to add a Root element at the top and also two attributes, modified xml below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Root abc="123" def="234">
<a>
  <b>
    <c>c</c>
    <d>d</d>
    <e>e</e>
    <f>f</f>
    <g>g</g>
    <h>h</h>
    <i>i</i>
    <j>j</j>
    <k>k</k>
    <l>l</l>
  </b>
</a>
</Root>
```

Please help me in modifying the schema so that the modified xml is valid according to the schema

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing the targetnamespace will remove the need for the namespaces in the XML document. The following XSD also shows how to add attributes.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<!--Created with Liquid Studio 2019 (https://www.liquid-technologies.com)-->
<xsd:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xsd:annotation>
        <xsd:documentation>Sampleschema</xsd:documentation>
    </xsd:annotation>
    <xsd:element name="root">
        <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element ref="a" />
            </xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:attribute name="abc" type="xsd:string" />
            <xsd:attribute name="def" type="xsd:int" />
        </xsd:complexType>
    </xsd:element>
    <xsd:element name="a" type="a" />
    <xsd:complexType name="aTopElmt">
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="a" type="a" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" />
        </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
    <xsd:complexType name="a">
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="b" type="b" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" />
        </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
    <xsd:complexType name="b">
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="c" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" />
            <xsd:element name="d" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" />
            <xsd:element name="e" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" />
            <xsd:element name="f" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" />
            <xsd:element name="g" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" />
            <xsd:element name="h" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" />
            <xsd:element name="i" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" />
            <xsd:element name="j" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" />
            <xsd:element name="k" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" />
            <xsd:element name="l" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" />
        </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:schema>
```

[image: Graphical Representation using Liquid XML Studio]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Created with Liquid Studio 2019 (https://www.liquid-technologies.com) -->
<root abc="string" def="-2200">
    <a>
        <b>
            <d>string</d>
            <e>string</e>
            <j>string</j>
            <l>string</l>
        </b>
    </a>
</root>
```